# How can I validate python code in a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am looking for a way to do the above within a coding class for students. The idea is to check in the background if the code the students created e.g.  returns the correct value or performs the correct routine.

That way I could make sure the code works and will be useful in the forthcoming cells. What would be the best way to do so and to give feedback/hints as to what was done wrong?

This should of course be not visible to the students as they should figure out the answers themselves. Should I send the code to be validated by some other kernel? Is there an optimal way?

Comment: Perhaps this is better suited for https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You could write tests for the tasks you hand out to your students. Depending on which ones fail proceed to print possible fixes.

Answer (score 1):

> This should of course be not visible to the students as they should figure out the answers themselves.

This is usually the wrong tactic. You should provide a set of test cases that expect correct output that the student can run their test against. Recall that Test-Driven Development teaches that application code should only be written to satisfy existing unit tests. Since you're assigning the application code: you need to write the unit tests to be passed!

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill for what you want to do, but [INGInious](https://github.com/UCL-INGI/INGInious) might help here. From the website:

> INGInious is a secure and automated exercises assessment platform
>   using your own tests, also providing a pluggable interface with your
>   existing LMS.

It offers all the infrastructure to test student code and give feedback.

Disclaimer: It is developed by people in my university